# after renaming directly on Heroku, can't access website anymore

Tags: github, heroku, web-applications, rename, bad-request

I am a very inexperienced therefore ignorant new developer. I don't like the auto generated app name, so before I consulted literature about how to correctly change app name on this platform, I simply went ahead and changed the name in the settings on Heroku. Heroku warned to update git also which I did by executing:

```
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

it seemed it was executed successfully. terminal showed:

```
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/newname.git
```

but when i tried to access the app at the new address, it showed as below. and the old address had stopped working of course. this is so frustrating.
Could anyone please tell me how I can make this work again? Thanks!!!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

: )
it turned out i still had the old allowed_host in the settings.py file. of course. after i updated it to the new app name, everything worked again!